# How to split text file in separate lines from open until close bracket?

Tags: python

I have a text file and I need to split it to separate lines. I want to separate them from `[` and until the closed bracket `]` and put the text in these brackets in separate lines. This is the example of my text file:

```
["ANION-PI   ASP-30-A     PHE-28-A     4.03 23.88 OD2:ASP:30:A    CD1:PHE:28:A    30.61   29 D   27 F nhb: 0 MS: 0 SS: 0 SB: 0 INTRA 1aa9A \t ASP-30-A     PHE-28-A     \t 82.70 91.40 \t AF-P01112-F1-model_v1.pdb\n", "ANION-PI   ASP-30-A     PHE-28-A       3.48   12.31   OD1:ASP:30:A    CE1:PHE:28:A     53.24\t   29 D   27 F \t nhb: 0  MS: 0  SS: 0  SB: 0 INTRA  AF-P01112-F1-model_v1\n"],
["ANION-PI   GLU-2097-A   TRP-2092-A   4.42 20.84 OE2:GLU:2097:A  CZ3:TRP:2092:A  42.75   45 E   40 W nhb: 0 MS: 0 SS: 0 SB: 0 INTRA 1apjA \t GLU-1297-A   TRP-1292-A   \t 85.20 90.10 \t AF-P35555-F5-model_v1.pdb\n", "ANION-PI   GLU-1297-A   TRP-1292-A     4.19    1.17   center          CZ3:TRP:1292:A   75.08\t 1296 E 1291 W \t nhb: 2  MS: 0  SS: 2  SB: 2 INTRA  AF-P35555-F5-model_v1\n"],
["ANION-PI   ASP-24-A     TYR-17-A     3.08 29.72 OD2:ASP:24:A    CZ:TYR:17:A     23.71   23 D   16 Y nhb: 1 MS: 1 SS: 0 SB: 0 INTRA 1awwA \t ASP-232-A    TYR-225-A    \t 90.60 91.40 \t AF-Q06187-F1-model_v1.pdb\n", "ANION-PI   ASP-232-A    TYR-225-A      4.18    2.55   OD2:ASP:232:A   CZ:TYR:225:A     57.49\t  231 D  224 Y \t nhb: 4  MS: 3  SS: 1  SB: 0 INTRA  AF-Q06187-F1-model_v1\n"]
```

Comment: `open('path.txt','r').readlines()`

Comment: You should probably use [RegEx](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp)

Comment: Please clarify: do you want to keep the `[ ]`? And what about the newline in the middle of the string? Should that be deleted?

Comment: Could you add an example of how you want the output to be

Comment: did you create this file? Maybe you should change code which write file and write data without `[ ]`.

Comment: what did you try? Where is your code? You can read it as one text, `split("\n")` and remove `[ ]` like in any other string.

Answer (score 1):

This will do what you've asked for but I'm not convinced that it's really what you want.

```
import re

with open('foo.txt') as data:
    for line in re.findall('\[.*?\]', data.read()):
        print(line)
```

**Output:**

```
["ANION-PI ASP-30-A PHE-28-A 4.03 23.88 OD2:ASP:30:A CD1:PHE:28:A 30.61 29 D 27 F nhb: 0 MS: 0 SS: 0 SB: 0 INTRA 1aa9A \t ASP-30-A PHE-28-A \t 82.70 91.40 \t AF-P01112-F1-model_v1.pdb\n", "ANION-PI ASP-30-A PHE-28-A 3.48 12.31 OD1:ASP:30:A CE1:PHE:28:A 53.24\t 29 D 27 F \t nhb: 0 MS: 0 SS: 0 SB: 0 INTRA AF-P01112-F1-model_v1\n"]
["ANION-PI GLU-2097-A TRP-2092-A 4.42 20.84 OE2:GLU:2097:A CZ3:TRP:2092:A 42.75 45 E 40 W nhb: 0 MS: 0 SS: 0 SB: 0 INTRA 1apjA \t GLU-1297-A TRP-1292-A \t 85.20 90.10 \t AF-P35555-F5-model_v1.pdb\n", "ANION-PI GLU-1297-A TRP-1292-A 4.19 1.17 center CZ3:TRP:1292:A 75.08\t 1296 E 1291 W \t nhb: 2 MS: 0 SS: 2 SB: 2 INTRA AF-P35555-F5-model_v1\n"]
["ANION-PI ASP-24-A TYR-17-A 3.08 29.72 OD2:ASP:24:A CZ:TYR:17:A 23.71 23 D 16 Y nhb: 1 MS: 1 SS: 0 SB: 0 INTRA 1awwA \t ASP-232-A TYR-225-A \t 90.60 91.40 \t AF-Q06187-F1-model_v1.pdb\n", "ANION-PI ASP-232-A TYR-225-A 4.18 2.55 OD2:ASP:232:A CZ:TYR:225:A 57.49\t 231 D 224 Y \t nhb: 4 MS: 3 SS: 1 SB: 0 INTRA AF-Q06187-F1-model_v1\n"]
```

Answer (score 0):

If that's the format of the contents of text file, you could do by using the [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) function:

```
from ast import literal_eval

with open('split_me.txt') as file:
    lists = literal_eval(''.join(file.read().splitlines()))
    lines = [lst[0] for lst in lists]

print('Lines:')
for i, line in enumerate(lines, start=1):
    print(f'{i}: {line!r}')
```

Output using your file:

```
Lines:
1: 'ANION-PI   ASP-30-A     PHE-28-A     4.03 23.88 OD2:ASP:30:A    CD1:PHE:28:A    30.61   29 D   27 F nhb: 0 MS: 0 SS: 0 SB: 0 INTRA 1aa9A \t ASP-30-A     PHE-28-A     \t 82.70 91.40 \t AF-P01112-F1-model_v1.pdb\n'
2: 'ANION-PI   GLU-2097-A   TRP-2092-A   4.42 20.84 OE2:GLU:2097:A  CZ3:TRP:2092:A  42.75   45 E   40 W nhb: 0 MS: 0 SS: 0 SB: 0 INTRA 1apjA \t GLU-1297-A   TRP-1292-A   \t 85.20 90.10 \t AF-P35555-F5-model_v1.pdb\n'
3: 'ANION-PI   ASP-24-A     TYR-17-A     3.08 29.72 OD2:ASP:24:A    CZ:TYR:17:A     23.71   23 D   16 Y nhb: 1 MS: 1 SS: 0 SB: 0 INTRA 1awwA \t ASP-232-A    TYR-225-A    \t 90.60 91.40 \t AF-Q06187-F1-model_v1.pdb\n'
```